# Data transformation with and without Min-max scaling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, non-linear-regression, data-transform

I am trying to test Tukey's Bulging Rule or Ladder of Powers ([Ref](http://www.math.smith.edu/%7Ebbaumer/mth247/labs/transformations.html) [Image](https://www.motleybytes.com/w/Tukeys_Bulging_Rule)). I discovered that I am able to reproduce the transformation (from right skewed to less right-skewed OR left skewed to less left-skewed) only if I scale my data.

[image: Tukey's Bulging Rule]

I chose exponential distribution and reciprocal transformation so that I can test his rule for the fourth quadrant i.e. use reciprocal transformation to change a right skewed distribution to relatively left-skewed. I do understand that taking `log` transformation will make the graph linear, but I wanted to test the reciprocal transformation.

Here are the steps:

*Import statements are in Reference Section 1 below to avoid clutter here.*

**1. Generate data**

```
x = np.arange(0.01,100,.1)
y = np.exp(x)
```

Here's the graph and corresponding histogram [Code in Reference section 2]. As we can see the data is nicely right-skewed.
[image: Hist and Data]

**2. Apply reciprocal transformation and generate corresponding graph and histogram**

```
y_prime = 1/y
```

Code for plotting is in Section 3.

[image: After applying reciprocal transformation]

**Problem:** The issue is that reciprocal transformation has changed the data, but the distribution is unchanged (it should have shifted from being right skewed to *less right* skewed). Why is this happening?

**Attempts to fix this issue:**
I tried to fix this by applying min-max scaling to the data. [Code is in Section 4.]
After min-max scaling `y` to `y_scaled` and then applying reciprocal transformation does show that the distribution changes from right skewed to *less-right-skewed*  (or left skewed). I am not sure why this is happening.

[image: y_scaled_hat and its Histogram]

**Question:** Why the distribution of transformation `y'=1/y` didn't change from right skewed to relatively less right skewed, but min-max scaling changed the distribution as expected?

---

I am using Python 3.7.

**Reference code:**

Section 1:

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
```

Section 2:

```
_=plt.hist(y,bins=50,density=True)
_=plt.plot(y)
```

Section 3:

```
_= plt.plot(y_prime)
_=plt.hist(y_prime,bins=50)
```

Section 4:

```
def minmaxscale(data):

    data_scaled=data.reshape(-1,1)
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data_scaled)
    data_scaled += 0.001
    return data_scaled

y_scaled = minmaxscale(y)
y_scaled_hat = 1/y_scaled
_= plt.plot(y_scaled_hat)
_=plt.hist(y_scaled_hat,bins=50)
```